# How do I connect to a Spring STOMP websocket using a native Android client?

Tags: spring, android-studio, kotlin, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm trying to do a small chatroom practice project using Android Studio and Spring Boot with kotlin. My problem is that I've already tried using many different libraries to connect the app to the websocket: For example: OkHttp, Scarlet, Ktor

But so far I haven't found a solution.

For the websocket code I followed the tutorial on the spring website. Here is the code:

```
@Controller
class MessageController {
    
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    fun greeting(message: String): String {
        return message
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    override fun configureMessageBroker(registry: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
    }
}
```

So my question is: How can i connect a android app to this websocket?

Answer (score 0):

STOMP is an application-level protocol which is used here on top of web sockets. Built-in clients rarely support this kind of protocol and in your case I don't believe Android has anything like it.

You most likely need a library that supports STOMP in order to do that. I'm the author of one such library called [Krossbow](https://joffrey-bion.github.io/krossbow/) if you're interested.

OkHttp, Scarlet, and Ktor don't support STOMP out of the box (at least not yet), but with Krossbow you can use Ktor or OkHttp as underlying web socket clients if you want.